# Trying to create the table tweetwords in hive

Tags: cloudera

I am trying this command to create a table tweetwords:

```
CREATE TABLE tweetwords as select id as id,
split(text,` `) as words from sampletweets;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 2:11 Invalid table alias or column reference ' ': (possible column names are: id, created_at, source, favorited, retweeted_status, entities, text, user, in_reply_to_screen_name)
```

Comment: Use ' ' instead of ` `. Here, your query should be 
CREATE TABLE tweetwords as select id as id,
split(text,' ') as words from sampletweets;

Answer (score 0):

Use ' ' instead of `` in query to split data.